# How to check if an element exist in a vector when the element may be NULL using base r functions

Tags: r, error-handling, return-value

Assume we have a vector and want to check if a variable is part of that vector. This is going to be used in a function as a error handling and the input can also be NULL

```
values <- c("ALL", "NON")
parameter <- "ALL"
```

the easy solution is to use is.element() or %in% but the parameter can be NULL and in that case we get an error in if()

```
parameter <- NULL

is.element(parameter, values)
logical(0)

if(is.element(parameter, values)){stop("invalid parameter")}

Error in if (is.element(parameter, values)) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Comment: You can check with `is.null(parameter)`  i.e. `!is.null(parameter) && is.element(parameter, values)`  or another option is to check the `length` i.e. `length(parameter) > 0  && is.element(parameter, values)`

Comment: That works, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to check.  The exact function to check is `is.null` which returns `TRUE` if it is `NULL`

```
!is.null(parameter) && is.element(parameter, values)
```

---

Other option is `length` which returns 0 for `NULL`

```
length(parameter) > 0 && is.element(parameter, values)
```

NOTE: Both the methods evaluate the second argument only if the first condition is TRUE.  So it will return `FALSE` whenever 'parameter' is `NULL`.  We can evaluate this in the same argument order as in the OP's `is.element` as

```
1:3 %in% 2
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
2 %in% 1:3
#[1] TRUE
```

returns different results.

NOTE: No packages used and here we assume that the OP pass vectors of same type

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `%in%` you can reverse the call and use `any` on top :

```
any(c("ALL", "NON") %in% NULL) # [1] FALSE
```

`c("ALL", "NON") %in% NULL` returns a logical of length `2` so we need `any`to get the output.

Another possibility is to use `purrr::has_element`, which handles this case :

```
library(purrr)
has_element(c("ALL", "NON"), NULL) # [1] FALSE
```

It's also stricter :

```
has_element(1, "1") # [1] FALSE
is.elements(1, "1") # [1] TRUE
has_element(list(iris), list(as.list(iris)))  # [1] FALSE
is.element(list(iris), list(as.list(iris))) # [1] TRUE
```